# Regex first result ($1) replacement as property of variable

Tags: javascript, regex

I am trying to find all instances starting with '%%msgStrs.' and ending with '%%' in a string and replace with that actual variable msgStrs['whatever']. Here is some sample code:

```
var msgStrs = {
    test: "1",
    test2: "2"
}

var msg = 'Test %%msgStrs.test%% test2 %%msgStrs.test2%%';
msg = msg.replace(/%%msgStrs\.(.*?)%%/g,msgStrs['$1']);
```

Here is the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rrp4n20z/).

The regex seems to be working and $1 is returning the right one, but it must be in the wrong type format as the msgStrs variable shows undefined. If I change the replace line to:

```
msg = msg.replace(/%%msgStrs\.(.*?)%%/g,"msgStrs['$1']");
```

This will show the correct string for $1.

Why won't it pull msgStrs.test and msgStrs.test2?

Comment: You must do that inside a callback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to perform this inside a callback:

```js
var msgStrs = {
    test: "1",
    test2: "2"
}

var msg = 'Test %%msgStrs.test%% test2 %%msgStrs.test2%%';
msg = msg.replace(/%%msgStrs\.(.*?)%%/g, function(match, group1) {
   return msgStrs[group1] ? msgStrs[group1] : match;
});

console.log(msg); // => Test 1 test2 2
```

Where `m` is the whole match and `g` is the captured submatch. If there is no value for the currently matched `g`, the whole match is returned (due to `msgStrs[g] ? msgStrs[g] : m;`).

Comment: can you rename the params to something noob-friendly like whole and match or all and sub?

Comment: I always think that `m` and `g` are self-explanatory, maybe for me only.

Comment: in the context of regexp, m means many and g means global, but maybe that's just me. point is, single-letters are often loaded in the mind of the coder. if replace's callback didn't skip the first param (or make it 99% useless), it would be a lot simpler...